# javascript variable scope in multiple calls

Tags: javascript, function

Below is a code little modified and lifted from javascript good parts.

I call this function twice after creating anonymously as can be seen.

```js
var fade = function(node, name) {
  var level = 1;
  var step = function() {
    var hex = level.toString(16);
    node.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF' + hex + hex;
    if (level < 15) {
      level += 1;
      //setTimeout(step, 100);
      console.log("in" + name + level)
    }
  };
  setTimeout(step, 100);
  console.log("out" + name + level)
};
```

When i call them with same second argument that is name="one" second call happens but the value of level is also same in both calls as can be seen in console log output "in" is printed only once

as below

```html
outone1 (index):34
outone1 (index):34
2inone2
```

```js
    fade(document.body, "one");
fade(document.body, "one");
```

On the other hand if i call below function twice with different arguments as below second call happens as earlier but the the value of level is not same in both calls as can be seen in console log output "in" is printed twice

as below

```html
outone1 (index):34
outtwo1 (index):34
inone2 (index):30
intwo2
```

```js
    fade(document.body, "one");

 fade(document.body, "two");
```

Question is why value of level is apparently shared across two calls when value of name argument is same?
whereas it is not the case when name is different.
Ideally console output should be similar with two "in" printed in both cases why is it that it is printed only once in first case and twice in second?

Comment: Can you clarify what intended behavior you're after?

Comment: So far there's not even a question.

Comment: i have modified it to state the question. this is a valid question, intended behaviour is it should behave same way in both calls, why is it that value of level is shared when called with same arguments. dont know why this is downvoted.

Comment: console `2inone2` means log 2 times inone2. Its same as `inone2, inone2`. So the behaviour is the same with identic and with different name arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding of the console output. For instance:

```
outone1 (index):34
outone1 (index):34
2inone2
```

The `2inone2` actually means:

```
inone2
inone2
```

The Chrome console tends to collapse repeated output with a number in front of the message to indicate how many times it happens.

Further there's no sharing of variable states happening here. What you're seeing that might seem indicative of variable sharing on the console is actually just a result of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.

For instance in:

```
outone1 (index):34
outtwo1 (index):34
inone2 (index):30
intwo2
```

When you call `fade(document.body, 'one')` and then `fade(document.body, 'two')` each calls `setTimeout` to start a timeout loop. `setTimeout` is an asynchronous call meaning the original functions are going to return immediately (hence the `outone1` and then `outtwo1`) then some time in the future (`100ms` in this example) the scheduled inner `step` functions will be called. That's why, on the console `inone2` and `intwo2` appear to trade places back and forth. There's no blocking and two functions are called within some milliseconds of each other. In fact the console output proves there is no sharing of state, otherwise you might expect:

```
inone2
intwo3
```

Does that clear up your question?

Comment: yes thanks a lot.  my bad how naive am i to not get even this. :(

Comment: No worries, you have to learn somewhere. Plus JavaScript can do some *strange* things if you're not terribly familiar with it.